# Wordpress CLI: Unable to import file. "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads." Permissions error?

Tags: php, wordpress, debian, raspbian

I am running Wordpress on a Debian Based (Raspbian Buster) LEMP server. For the most part, everything is working fine except some problems with uploading photos using the command line interface. I have many pictures in my servers `~/Pictures` folder that I am trying to upload to Wordpress using the command line interface.

The problem is when I navigate to the root directory of my Wordpress installation and run the following command:

```
wp media import ~/Pictures/*.jpg
```

I get the following errors

> Warning: Unable to import file '/home/Danran/Pictures/img_0754.jpg'. Reason: The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2020/03.

for each corresponding file. I am fairly certain that this is some sort of permissions error, but I don't want to risk tinkering around with permissions in my wordpress directory without some sort of guidance by a pro.

How can I get rid of this error in Wordpress CLI and successfully import my photos to Wordpress using the wp-cli (Wordpress CLI)?

Answer (score 1):

could you please verify that you have write permissions in the uploads directory?

if u are using apache, normally what I do is set the `www-data` group as the owner of that directory

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```

but, if what you want is to know if it is a permissions problem, simply set the permissions to `777` of that directory, and try to upload the files again... if you succeed, then it is a problem permissions, and setting them to 777 grants the cli access to that folder.

```
chmod 777 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```

Once you upload all of your photos with the CLI, you can change the permissions back to their original with `chmod -R 755` on the same uploads folder you originally modified.

However, I usually set the permissions as follows ..

`Directories: 644`

`Files: 755`

```
find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

***EDIT1***
Compare it with yours:

`/var/www/wordpress/`

```
root@www:/var/www# ls -l
total 212
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup   420 Nov 30  2017 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup 19935 Jan  1  2019 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  7368 Sep  2  2019 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  6939 Sep  2  2019 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data nogroup  4096 Dec 18 17:16 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup   369 Nov 30  2017 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  2283 Jan 20  2019 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  2898 Jan  7  2019 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data root     3310 Jan  7 11:54 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data nogroup  4096 Jan  7 15:17 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  3955 Oct 10 18:52 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 20 www-data nogroup 12288 Dec 18 17:16 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  2504 Sep  2  2019 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  3326 Sep  2  2019 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup 47597 Dec  9 08:30 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  8483 Sep  2  2019 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup 19120 Oct 15 11:37 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup 31112 Sep  2  2019 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  4764 Nov 30  2017 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup  3150 Jul  1  2019 xmlrpc.php
```

`/var/www/wordpress/wp-content`

```
root@www:/var/www/wp-content# ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  7 14:52 cache
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data nogroup    28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  7 11:55 languages
drwxr-xr-x 11 www-data nogroup  4096 Jan  8 16:24 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data nogroup  4096 Jan  7 13:51 themes
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  7 14:52 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  7 14:50 uploads
```

Comment: What command can I use to output the write permissions and verify the correct permissions are being used? I am using ngninx, not apache (see Original post), and I believe I used chown -R www-data:www-data /wordpressrootdirectory on the root directory. Shouldn't that carry over to all subdirectories?

Comment: Should there be a sudo before those commands? I am getting a permission denied without using sudo.

Comment: yes, -R option means ```recursive```, u can use ```ls -l ``` command into root directory to check permissions

Comment: @DanRan if your standard user doesn't belong to group ```su```, then you need to run the commands like ```sudo```

Comment: I just ran your above commands and changed permissions as noted. I DID use sudo before them. However, I am still getting the exact same error when trying to import Pictures folder in with wp-cli. Any other ideas?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  8 15:29 admin
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 21 21:10 html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   420 Nov 30  2017 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19935 Jan  1  2019 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7368 Sep  2  2019 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   203 Feb 21 23:02 robots.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   311 Mar 15 13:03 sitemap.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  6939 Sep  2  2019 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  8 15:58 wp-admin

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   369 Nov 30  2017 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2283 Jan 20  2019 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3394 Mar 15 14:00 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2898 Jan  7  2019 wp-config-sample.php
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 15 14:12 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3955 Oct 10 17:52 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 20 www-data www-data 12288 Dec 18 16:16 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2504 Sep  2  2019 wp-links-opml.php

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3326 Sep  2  2019 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 47597 Dec  9 07:30 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  8483 Sep  2  2019 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19120 Oct 15 10:37 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 31112 Sep  2  2019 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4764 Nov 30  2017 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3150 Jul  1  2019 xmlrpc.php

Comment: @DanRan Could you post what the terminal shows you when you run ```ls -l``` in the ```wp-content``` directory?

Comment: My standard user doesn't belong to the group su, fyi.

Comment: here is the output of `ls -l` in the `wp-content` directory. `lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   71 Feb 22 21:30 db.php -> /var/www/oddcake.net/wp-content/plugins/query-monitor/wp-content/db.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 13:54 mu-plugins
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 13:45 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 13:55 themes
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 13:55 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  8 15:54 uploads`

Comment: @DanRan please see my EDIT1

Comment: I don't fully understand what EDIT1 indicates I should be doing. I'm assuming I should be cross-referencing my output with your output? If so, then `ls -l` in `/var/www/wordpress/` is showing all files and folders as www-data www-data. `ls -l` in `/var/www/wordpress/wp-content` is showing all files and folders as www-data www-data as well.

Comment: @DanRan Oh !, I'm sorry, maybe I won't explain myself well, I just showed you the output of my terminal so you could compare it with yours. Have you also tried to run the command with a user ```su```? try ```sudo su``` then  ```wp media import ~ / Pictures / *. jpg```

Comment: when using `sudo wp media import ~/Pictures/*.jpg` i get the error message "Error: YIKES! It looks like you're running this as root. You probably meant to run this as the user that your WordPress installation exists under. If you REALLY mean to run this as root, we won't stop you, but just bear in mind that any code on this site will then have full control of your server, making it quite DANGEROUS."

Comment: I don't want my site to be insecure by using root to import files.

Comment: @DanRan please try ```chmod -R 777 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads``` and next ```wp media import ~/Pictures/*.jpg```

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads` worked. Once I am done uploading using the command line, how do I change the permissions back to the original?

Comment: @DanRan Great!.. I'm glad to know that you've got what you want .. Please, can u mark my answer as the correct answer?.. to leave the permissions as they were ... run ```chmod -R 755 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting Directories to 644 and files to 755? Is this tighter security? Why is this different than the original said permissions? Also, i edited your answer and will mark as complete once your recommended permsissions answer is posted. Sorry for such a long delay. Thanks for all of your help! –